# Using constructor parameter variable names during object instantiation in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

When declaring a new instance of an object in python, why would someone use the names of the variables from the parameters at instatntiation time? Say you have the following object:

```
class Thing: 
    def __init__(self,var1=None,var2=None):
        self.var1=var1
        self.var2=var2
```

The programmer from here decides to create an instance of this object at some point later and enters it in the following way:

```
NewObj = Thing(var1=newVar,var2=otherVar)
```

Is there a reason why someone would enter it that way vs. just entering the newVar/otherVar variables into the constructor parameters without using "var1=" and "var2="? Like below:

```
NewObj = Thing(newVar,otherVar)
```

I'm fairly novice at using python, and I couldn't find anything about this specific sort of syntax even if it seems like a fairly simple/straightforward question

Comment: Do you know that the same thing can be done for any other function calls too, not only constructors?

Comment: So people don't have to remember the argument order (when writing or reading the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is clarity, not for the computer, but for yourself and other humans.

```
class Calculation: 
    def __init__(self, low=None, high=None, mean=None):
        self.low=low
        self.high=high
        self.mean=mean

...

# with naming (notice how ordering is not important)
calc = Calculation(mean=0.5, low=0, high=1)

# without naming (now order is important and it is less clear what the numbers are used for)
calc = Calculation(0, 1, 0.5)
```

Note that the same can be done for any function, not only when initializing an object.

Comment: Ah okay, I figured this was just for clarity purposes, I just wanted to be sure that it wasn't some strange syntax to do with the default arguments or something similar